# Why does a normal function need to be wrapped with viewModelScope.launch?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

1: In my mind,a suspend fun should be launched in another suspend fun or `viewModelScope.launch{ }`, `withContext{ }` ... , `filterItems()` is only a normal function, I don't know why `filterItems()` need to be wrapped with `viewModelScope.launch{ }` in the function `filterTasks()`, could you tell me ?

2: In the function `filterTasks()`, `viewModelScope.launch{ }` will launch in coroutines, it's asynchronous, I think `return result` maybe be launched before I get the `result` from `viewModelScope.launch{}`,  so the `result` maybe null,  is the code correct?

**Code**

```
   private fun filterTasks(tasksResult: Result<List<Task>>): LiveData<List<Task>> {       
        val result = MutableLiveData<List<Task>>()

        if (tasksResult is Success) {
            isDataLoadingError.value = false
            viewModelScope.launch {
                result.value = filterItems(tasksResult.data, getSavedFilterType())
                //return filterItems(tasksResult.data, getSavedFilterType())  //It will cause error.
            }
        } else {
            result.value = emptyList()
            showSnackbarMessage(R.string.loading_tasks_error)
            isDataLoadingError.value = true
        }

        return result //I think it maybe be launched before I get the result from viewModelScope.launch{}
    }


    private fun filterItems(tasks: List<Task>, filteringType: TasksFilterType): List<Task> {
        val tasksToShow = ArrayList<Task>()
        // We filter the tasks based on the requestType
        for (task in tasks) {
            when (filteringType) {
                ALL_TASKS -> tasksToShow.add(task)
                ACTIVE_TASKS -> if (task.isActive) {
                    tasksToShow.add(task)
                }
                COMPLETED_TASKS -> if (task.isCompleted) {
                    tasksToShow.add(task)
                }
            }
        }
        return tasksToShow
    }
```

Comment: Its not that good to do computational intensive tasks in Main thread, they should have used the `Dispatchers.Default`. But anyway they returned the result (LiveData) and let the other thread to push the result when its available. And they could have used the `(Mutable)StateFlow` instead of `LiveData`, the project is may be outdated (last updated 8 months ago), so chances are they used what could do the work in hurry and never updated the code.

Comment: Is `getSavedFilterType()` a `suspend fun`? If not, then you don't need to `launch` a coroutine to run `filterItems(...)`, unless it would block the current thread for too long. Also, you cannot `return` a value from a launched coroutine: it just is a fire and forget operation that runs in the scope it was launched in. If you want to return a value from a coroutine, then use `async` to return a `Deferred<T>` value of type `T` and `await` it elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't, **unless** it performs some heavy work **and** you want to move it to a background thread, which is the case here. Here the author just wanted to disjoint the work so the live data can be updated with an empty list first, and the filtered list later(computationally intensive to get), but forgot to do it out of the main thread.

In this particular case the author may have forgotten to add a background dispatcher as a parameter

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)
```

hence, in this scenario the intended behavior was not achieved, so you see this "nonsensical" coroutine.

I think you can contribute to the project with a fix :)

Answer (score 3):

yes, you are right. but if you looked up the implementation of the launch {} such in lifecycleScope.launch {} or viewModelScope.launch {} you would find out the "**block**" which is ***"the coroutine code which will be invoked in the context of the provided scope"*** is cast to be **suspend**, so any block of code between launch {} is suspend code block. so in your example filterItems is cast to suspend under the hood and it's wrapped with viewModelScope.launch{ } to do its heavy task not in main thread.

```
public fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    // the below line is doing the magic
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job {
    val newContext = newCoroutineContext(context)
    val coroutine = if (start.isLazy)
        LazyStandaloneCoroutine(newContext, block) else
        StandaloneCoroutine(newContext, active = true)
    coroutine.start(start, coroutine, block)
    return coroutine
}
```

Comment: In this case viewModelScope will be used as the scope of this launch function, which internally uses Dispatchers.Main.immediate, so, even if the block gets wrapped in a suspend function, it still gets executed in the main thread, thus blocking the app and possibly causing an ANR.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the code looks suspicious, main reason is that it launches the `filterItems` coroutine into the `Main` dispatcher, basically just postponing the moment when `filterItems` will run on the GUI thread. If `filterItems` takes long to complete, it will block the GUI; if it doesn't take long, then why would you launch a concurrent coroutine in the first place?

Furthermore, on an architectural level, I don't see a reason why you'd have a function returning `LiveData<List<Task>>` when you can just have a `suspend fun` returning `List<Task>`.

Comment: They are using MVVM-Live with Data Binding, that's why they expose the items on a LiveData object. They just use transformations on it so it becomes easier to use cached/retrieve fresh data when needed.